# xpath query get child element

Tags: php, curl, dom, xpath

I'm currently using the following address via PHP CURL / Xpath to grab some data:

```
 $url: http://v1.syndication.nhschoices.nhs.uk/organisations/hospitals/name/trafford?apikey=TBQBMMKR
```

Code used:

```
 $ch = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 $document = new DOMDocument;
 libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
 $document->loadHTML($output);
 $document->encoding = 'utf-8';
 $xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
 $orgcodes= $xpath->query('//dd[2]');

 $results = array();

 $iCnt = 0; 
 foreach ($orgcodes as $orgcode){ 
 $results[$iCnt]['orgcode'] = $document->saveHTML($orgcode); $iCnt++; }
 $n = 0; 

 for($iCnt = 0, $cnt = count($results); 
 $iCnt < $cnt; $iCnt++){ 
 $n++; 

 echo $results[$iCnt]['orgcode'];

 }?>
```

**I want to echo the ODS codes like so :**

**RM321**

**RW3TR**

But i'm getting the following instead:

RM321

53.4540634155273

RW3TR

53.4540634155273

Any ideas? I'm guessing its do with the xquery but I'm at a puzzle.

Comment: Does this `//dt[.="ODS code:"]/following-sibling::dd[1]` works for you?

Comment: Apologies for my late reply - That worked perfectly! many thanks for your prompt answer!